# mod_rewrite acting strange when moved to .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I had this rewrite rule in my httpd conf file:

```
RewriteRule (.*?)\.html $1.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [NC]
```

It worked fine. But when I place it into my .htaccess for that same virtual host, it's now returning the entire document path for $1 instead of the http host. All it needs to do is replace "html" with "php".

I obviously I don't understand how .htaccess works with rewrite rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a leading slash in your rule's target:

```
RewriteRule (.*?)\.html /$1.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [NC]
```

Also, you can get rid of the `?%{QUERY_STRING}` bit in the target as well. Query strings are automatically appended if there isn't a **?**.

Comment: Awesome that works. What's the deal with needing the leading slash? It thinks it's a local directory otherwise?

Comment: @DanielE Apache tries to guess if a target is a file-system path or a URL path, in .htaccess a target without a leading slash is guessed as a file-system path. See the differences between the per-server and per-directory examples in the docs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

Answer (score 0):

My eyes nearly bleed looking at that ugly thing...

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*).html?(.*)$ $1\.php?$2 [NC]
```

Comment: If you know regex mod_rewrite almost makes sense.  But seriously, I don't quite get why people use it, just post instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [nc]
```